# What type of data ingestion does Azure Data Factory use?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure, azure-data-factory

This article [data-ingestion](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/data-ingestion) says that there are two types of data ingestion

> Data can be streamed in real time or ingested in batches.

What type of data ingestion does Azure Data Factory's pipelines use when moving data from On-Premises/Cloud sources services to Azure Services (Azure Blob Storage, Azure Data Lake Store, etc)

While going through the documentation I found the following:

> ADF provides the services and tooling to compose and integrate data,
>   build data pipelines, and **monitor their status in real time**

Does that mean that Data is streamed in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following picture found in the documentation, it has a Batch Ingest

[image]

You could also use [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger) to move data incrementally. But it is not real time. There is frequency limitation.